# Failed to retrieve UCF id

Tags: email, drag-and-drop, lotus-notes, documentum, emc

I recently encountered an issue with my Lotus Documentum Integration (LDI). After trying to drag an email from lotus notes over to the LDI drag n drop window and dropped it, I get the following Lotus Notes error:

```
=================
Error Information
=================
Program: Archive
Exception: Attempted 5 retries. Aborting.
FuncRef: saveItems

BaseType:
Emc.Documentum.FS.Runtime.ServiceInvocationException: Failed to retrieve UCF id.
   at EAIF.DataSource.EAIFWebServicesDataSource.CreateObject(String folderPath, String filePath, String objectType, String objectFormat, String objectName,     DocbaseAttributeCollection attrs)
   at LDIArchive.ArchiveForm.saveItems()

Stack Trace:
   at LDIArchive.ArchiveForm.saveItems()
   at LDIArchive.ArchiveForm.btnFinish_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)

Inner Program: EAIFramework.NET
Inner Exception: Failed to retrieve UCF id.
Inner FuncRef: CreateObject

Inner BaseType:
Emc.Documentum.FS.Runtime.ServiceInvocationException: Failed to retrieve UCF id.
   at EAIF.DataSource.EAIFWebServicesDataSource.CreateObject(String folderPath, String filePath, String objectType, String objectFormat, String objectName, DocbaseAttributeCollection attrs)
   at LDIArchive.ArchiveForm.saveItems()

Inner Stack Trace:
   at EAIF.DataSource.EAIFWebServicesDataSource.CreateObject(String folderPath, String filePath, String objectType, String objectFormat, String objectName, DocbaseAttributeCollection attrs)
   at LDIArchive.ArchiveForm.saveItems()
```

Trying to do some research online, but no luck. 
Much appreciated anyone could help. Cheers

Comment: Just quick info that LDI is a Documentum Client for Lotus Notes

Comment: Does any part of the LDI product seem to be talking to Documentum successfully?  I'm not familiar with LDI at all, but I'm wondering if it is even pointing to the right Documentum DFS endpoint.

Comment: Thanks @unicron, I'm only able to logon to LDI from notes, and that was it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've recently found an answer to my question above. Bascially, I need to shut down lotus notes, remove UCF folder under Documentum folder within c:/Document and Settings/<-my user id>/ and restart Notes. This will fix the problem